If $P(x)$ is a fifth degree polynomial such that $P(x)+1$ is dividable by $(x-1)^3$ and $P(x)-1$ is dividable by $(x+1)^3$, How to find $P(x)$
I saw this question:

If $P(x)$ is a fifth degree polynomial such that $P(x)+1$ is dividable by $(x-1)^3$ and $P(x)-1$ is dividable by $(x+1)^3$,find $P(x)$.

I tried my best to find such function but I couldn't,somehow I got that this function doesn't exist which I refuse to believe because these type of questions always have an answer it is likely that I make a mistake somewhere.
So assume $P(x)+1 =(x-1)^3(x-a)(x-b)$ and $P(x)-1=(x+1)^3(x-c)(x-d)$
$2= (x-1)^3(x-a)(x-b)- (x+1)^3(x-c)(x-d)$ for all $x$
If we substitute  $x=0$ we have $-ab-cd=2$
Using the fact that the result of the sum of roots is the coefficient of $x^4$ which should be zero
$$-3-a-b-3+c+d=0$$
$$c+d-a-b=6 \tag{*} $$
If we substitute $x= 1$ we get $1-c-d+cd = -\frac 1 4$
If we substitute $x=-1$ we get $1+a+b+ab=-\frac 1 4$
Adding  the last two equalities  we get
$$a+b-c-d+2 +(ab+cd)= -\frac 1 2$$
$$a+b-c-d+2 +(-2)= -\frac 1 2$$
$a+b-c-d=-\frac 1 2$ which contradicts (*)

This is very hard to follow. Try explaining your steps more clearly. For example, I can't see where you are getting the $-3-a-b-3+c+d=0$ equation. Is it "clearly" the coefficient of something?

@JoshB. It is the sum of the coefficients of $x^4$ because $(x-t_1)(x- t_2) \dots (x-t_m) = (x^n - (\sum_{k=1}^n t_k )x^{n-1}  + \sum_{m=2}^{n}c_m x^{n-m}$ and since $2= (x-1)^3(x-a)(x-b)- (x+1)^3(x-c)(x-d)$ for all $x$ then the coefficient of $x^4$ in $(x-1)^3(x-a)(x-b)$ minus the coefficient of $x^4$ in $(x+1)^3(x-c)(x-d)$ is 0

Try re-wording the question so that the remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-1)^3$ is $-1$ and when divided by $(x+1)^3$ the remainder is 1 and see if that gets you anywhere. I'll post a longer answer later unless someone beats me to it.

...my point was more that the logic and equations should be cleaned up. When you say you summed the roots, how did you know the roots? What polynomial? Where are we substituting $x$ into, is it $P$ or this new polynomial we have created? There are a lot of questions that I have just reading the narrative. Please clean up the question and your attempt at a solution so we can help.

@JoshB. I forgot to write that  assume $P(x)+1 =(x-1)^3(x-a)(x-b)$ and $P(x)-1=(x+1)^3(x-c)(x-d)$ some how I completely forgot

Is there a reason you're assuming $P(x)$ is monic?

@BrianMoehring the coefficient of $x^5$ should be the same in $t_1(x+1)^3(x-c)(x-d)$ and $t_2(x-1)^3(x-a)(x-b)$ ($t_1= t_2$)so that all of these steps will be the same but with extra constant say $t$ i.e $(x-1)^3(x-a)(x-b)-(x+1)^3(x-c)(x-d)=2t$ and $ab+cd = -2t$ and so on

Right... but it won't impact the sum of roots, so considering a "$t$" would fix your contradiction.

@BrianMoehring ahaa... Now I see thank you very much.

We shouldn't typically expect solutions for systems like the one you wrote, which has $5$ equations but only $4$ unknowns. On the other hand, your ansatzes are not full general polynomials satisfying the condition, but rather only general monic polynomials satisfying the condition.
Hint We can avoid most of the computation solving a quadratic system (in $5$ or $6$ variables) via some simple observations. First, since $(x \pm 1)^3$ divides $P(x) \mp 1$, $(x \pm 1)^2$ divides $(P(x) \mp 1)' = P'(x)$. But $P'$ has degree $4$, so
$$P'(x) = A (x - 1)^2 (x + 1)^2 .$$

 Since $P$ must be odd (consider how $P$ behaves under the replacement $x \rightsquigarrow -x$), $P(0) = 0$, so integrating gives $$P(x) = A \left(\frac15 x^5 - \frac23 x^3 + x\right) .$$ Finally, since $(x - 1) \mid (P(x) + 1)$, $P(1) + 1 = 0$, which fixes $A = -\frac{15}{8}$.


You beat me to it, @TravisWillse, with an answer that was precisely what I was thinking of. Thus I needn’t bother posting mine. (plus 1)

I don't see why $P$ should be odd. Some additional hint would be great.

@JensSchwaiger You don't need that part (my guess is Travis Willse is using a uniqueness argument).  Instead, just note that $P'(x)$ is an even function.  In such a case, use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the substitution $x \to -x$ to show $P(-1) + P(1) = 2P(0)$.

@BrianMoehring Ah, that's even better!

I see. The function $x\mapsto P(x)-P(0)$ is odd. And $P(\pm 1)\pm 1=0$.
